# when i export pdf the second time in access it overwrites the previously created pdf file

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2013

i have access application that i can scan/attach documents and then export to pdf;
after the scan is complete the file shows in a subform as jpg format and when i click on convert to pdf
it converts the list of images to pdf no problem, the problem when i scan again it overwrites the previous pdf file and the exported file contains a blank first page. (sorry for bad english)

this is the vba code for the convert to pdf button

```
Private Sub CommandConvertToPdf_Click()

Dim Numberofdocuments As Integer
Numberofdocuments = DCount("IDD", "QPicOfConseller01")
If Numberofdocuments = 0 Then
MsgBox "áÇÊæÌÏ ÕæÑÉ áÊÍæíáåÇ", , "ÕÝÍÉ ãÍãæÏ ÚÈÏ ÇáÛÝÇÑ"
End
Else

    SetPathOfFiles
    NumDoc = Me.IDD
    
    
    If Len(Dir(PathOfFile & Forms![Form1]![IDD], vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir PathOfFile & Forms![Form1]![IDD]
            End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportToPdf", acViewPreview, , , acHidden
    DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "ReportToPdf", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", PathOfFile & NumDoc & "\" & NumDoc & ".pdf"
      
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "ReportToPdf", acSaveNo

End If

        If Me.OptionDeletePicAfterConvertPDF = -1 Then
                DoCmd.GoToControl "ImagesSubform"
                DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDelete
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Me.PicView.Requery
        End If

Dim Ttb2 As Recordset
Set Ttb2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Image")
Ttb2.AddNew
Ttb2!\[IDD\] = Forms!\[Form1\]!\[IDD\]
Ttb2!\[Path\] = PathOfFile & NumDoc & "" & NumDoc & ".pdf"
Ttb2.Update
Me.ImagesSubform.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Before exporting to PDF, check that the file exists. If so, rename or delete it before you run the export.

Comment: And/Or assign a unique name to PDF when it is created.